# How to get recent 5 fields based on date and time which are passed as varchar

Tags: mysql

i am trying to get the recent 5 orders based on **date_of_order** and **time_of_order** fields in the below table and the data type of both these fields is **varchar** and here order_child_id is some random number which is not stored in order.

How can I write the query for this?

order_details_child table:

```
+------------------+------------+---------------+---------------+
| order_child_id   | vendor_id  | date_of_order | time_of_order |
+------------------+------------+---------------+---------------+
| 2000010313044428 | 5060091713 | 2015-03-11    | 16:44:28      | 
| 2000010313044920 | 5060091713 | 2015-03-13    | 16:49:20      | 
| 2000010313044951 | 5060091713 | 2015-03-11    | 16:49:51      | 
| 2002880313043941 | 5000818755 | 2015-03-13    | 16:39:41      | 
| 2002880313044029 | 5000818755 | 2015-03-12    | 16:40:29      | 
| 3000010313044555 | 5060091713 | 2015-03-12    | 16:45:55      | 
| 4000010313044555 | 5000818755 | 2015-03-13    | 16:45:55      | 
+------------------+------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
select od.*
from order_details od
order by date_of_order desc, time_of_order desc
limit 5;
```

You should store dates and times in the native format.  But if you can't for some reason, your formats are the right way to store them as strings.